# HTTP 404 error when installing R package from public repo on Github

Tags: r

I'm trying to install an R package from a public Github (https://github.com/verena-zuber/demo_AMD):

devtools::install_github("verena-zuber/demo_AMD")

Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
HTTP error 404.
Not Found

Did you spell the repo owner (`verena-zuber`) and repo name (`demo_AMD`) correctly?

- If spelling is correct, check that you have the required permissions to access the repo.
  As far as I can see the repro is public. Do you have any idea what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, it's not a package per se. It's just a few .R (and .Rmd) files collected together :). Therefore you can't install it as a package. However, you can download the whole set and use it sourcing the .R files, like:

```
source("summary_mvMR_SSS.R")
source("summary_mvMR_BF.R")
```

You can check in .Rmd how it's done.

Regards,
Grzegorz